# How pass info with context child to parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass info from child component to parent component, both are different files and are in different folders.

I'm using context with consumer and provider. When child is consumer and the provider is parent it works. But I want to pass the info to child as producer and parent as consumer.

I've created a folder called contexts with a file called MapContext.js with this code:

```
import React from 'react';

const MapContext = React.createContext(null);

export default MapContext;
```

Child component is called Map.js, and when the state change pass the info as you can see here:

```
render() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
    return (
      <MapContext.Provider value={zoom} >
        <div className="Menu">
          <MenuInfo lng={lng} lat={lat} zoom={zoom} />
          <PitchComponent map={this.map} />
          <div id="map" />
        </div>
      </MapContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And Parent component is called Navbar where has a button to create a modal component to show all info.

```
render() {
    return (
      <MapContext.Consumer>
      { context => ( console.log(context) ) }
      </MapContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

However, always return null. Dont receive info.
How can I solve it?

If is not possible... how can I do it?? create an event to subscribe me??
I dont want pass info using this.props.parent(info) because there are a n components between parent component and child component, one component is in navbar and the other is in the body, and I think is a dirty solution.

Thanks

Comment: What data are you trying to pass from the child to the parent? Can that data live in the parent? https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Finally I used react-observable-store, thanks!!

Comment: if you want to pass the info back to parent, why not use callback method? You use the producer/consumer pattern as described in the React documentation. And when zoom changes, then you invoke a zoomChanged event from the child. Unless I am missing somehing here...